# Clustering MySQL for Magento 2.0 installation

Tags: mysql, magento, cluster-computing, magento2, galera

I'm planning to setup a Magento 2.0 installation using MySQL Cluster o MySQL Galera Cluster for a highly available DB. One of the restrictions for these is that every table should have a PK. To my surprise, not every table on Magento 2.0 Community Edition has a PK. Most of them have one, but there are a few that don't.

Has anyone achieved a Magento installation with a highly available clustered DB? How did you manage that? I was thinking about just adding auto-incremental PKs to the tables that don't have a PK, but that could mean problems for future Magento upgrades with schema changes.

What would you do?

EDIT: These are the tables that would be troublesome:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------+------+----------+--------+
| tbl                                                          | engine | nopk | ftidx    | gisidx |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------+------+----------+--------+
| magento.cataloginventory_stock_status_tmp                    | MEMORY |      |          |        |
| magento.catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1                        | InnoDB |      | FULLTEXT |        |
| magento.catalog_category_product_index_tmp                   | MEMORY | NOPK |          |        |
| magento.catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity | InnoDB | NOPK |          |        |
| magento.catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_video     | InnoDB | NOPK |          |        |
| magento.catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_tmp                | MEMORY |      |          |        |
| magento.catalog_product_index_eav_tmp                        | MEMORY |      |          |        |
| magento.catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_tmp           | MEMORY |      |          |        |
| magento.catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_tmp           | MEMORY |      |          |        |
| magento.catalog_product_index_price_bundle_tmp               | MEMORY |      |          |        |
| magento.catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_tmp          | MEMORY |      |          |        |
| magento.catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_tmp              | MEMORY |      |          |        |
| magento.catalog_product_index_price_downlod_tmp              | MEMORY |      |          |        |
| magento.catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp                | MEMORY |      |          |        |
| magento.catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_tmp              | MEMORY |      |          |        |
| magento.catalog_product_index_price_opt_tmp                  | MEMORY |      |          |        |
| magento.catalog_product_index_price_tmp                      | MEMORY |      |          |        |
| magento.catalog_url_rewrite_product_category                 | InnoDB | NOPK |          |        |
| magento.cms_block                                            | InnoDB |      | FULLTEXT |        |
| magento.cms_page                                             | InnoDB |      | FULLTEXT |        |
| magento.customer_grid_flat                                   | InnoDB |      | FULLTEXT |        |
| magento.oauth_nonce                                          | InnoDB | NOPK |          |        |
| magento.sales_creditmemo_grid                                | InnoDB |      | FULLTEXT |        |
| magento.sales_invoice_grid                                   | InnoDB |      | FULLTEXT |        |
| magento.sales_order_grid                                     | InnoDB |      | FULLTEXT |        |
| magento.sales_shipment_grid                                  | InnoDB |      | FULLTEXT |        |
| magento.widget_instance_page_layout                          | InnoDB | NOPK |          |        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------+------+----------+--------+
```

Comment: What solution did you end up using?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar task a few months ago: to evaluate the best high availability DB solution that would fit our project (Java web app + MySQL).

I started evaluating Galera Cluster first and I've learnt that if one tries to just use DB clustering with an application that wasn't written with clustering in mind, chances are that it won't just work but it might need code adjustments. We could have adapted our code in most areas but we hit a blocking obstacle. Our app uses XA transactions, which are not supported by Galera. As we can't get rid of XA transactions in the near future, we cant use Galera (so far).

So I've switched to the next option which is: Master-Slave replication with automatic fail-over. Not that elegant as a cluster solution, especially that in this setup the slave might be behind the master with a few seconds which means that in case of a master crash, there might be some lost data (not much). We are currently still evaluating this approach and all looks nice so far.

Now.. if I were you I would try to make Magento work with Galera cluster first. As you said, you will have to modify the schema to make it compatible with Galera but you will need to be careful with future upgrades. We use the following issue/support trackers: MantisBT and osTicket which I had to customize both, changing both the PHP code and the database schema. I perform all the upgrades by hand. I must be very careful indeed but other that that, it is not a big deal. I guess if you have enough patience you can do the same on Magento.

Besides the tables that you must add a PK to, I see that there are tables that use the MEMORY engine. As far as I know Galera only supports InnoDB engine and it has some experimental support for MyIsam. While the PK stuff is easier to fix, fitting this MEMORY engine stuff to Galera might be harder to achieve.
See an interesting discussion here exactly on running [Magento with Galera](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/#!topic/codership-team/S37YdcDEEog)

Finally, if you decide that it is too hard to go with Galera (if possible at all), you have other HA options, like Master-Slave replication for example. I don't see any reason for it not to work in your case.

As a last word: I've learnt that bringing HA into the project is not easy. But it's a fun and fulfilling task. :-)
Just let as know what approach did you go in the end. It might be very useful for others too.

Comment: Mmmm. Going for master-slave wouldn't let me scale horizontally for write operations, right? I was aiming to be able to get to a solution growth-friendly too...

Comment: @manugarciac Right, you can only scale the reads. For horizontally scaling writes you might consider using a multi-master set-up instead (I did not use it myself). But be careful that unlike Galera, this is asynchronous (or semi-synchronous at best). Check this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-semisync.html